# How to create new Schema same as an existing one in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question in mongoDB. I have a `user` schema with different fields and methods. But I want to when deleting a user from this schema to place it in another schema for example `deleted-users` schema.

Should I create the `deleted-users` schema with the same exact fields but different name ?

Or is there a better way to this

Comment: You shoul create array in Schema and add deleted-users to there

Comment: @HazratGafulov I don't get it. Can you please write it in code